# Поиск текстовых значений в определенно ограниченных столбцах и строчках

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Как найти текстовое значение?

При выполнении данного кода ниже компилятор вообще ничего не выводит:

```
import pandas as pd
fp='C:/Users/CodeMaker/Downloads/geoMapj.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(fp)
exs=df.iloc[1:17,0:0]
for search in exs.items():
    if search == 'China':
        print('Win')
    else:
        print('Fail')
```

Хочу чтобы выводилось `Win` или `Fail` при нахождении определенного текстового значения.

Comment: если код ничего не выдаёт, значит `exs.items()` пустой. Могу предположить, что ошибка в `exs=df.iloc[1:17,0:0]`, а именно со срезом `0:0`. Сейчас вы 'отрезаете' все значения

Comment: Я проверял, компилятор выдает следущее `Columns: []
Index: [China, St Helena, Singapore, South Korea, Israel, Hong Kong, Switzerland, Luxembourg, United States, Ireland, Netherlands, Norway, Denmark, Canada, United Kingdom, Australia]`

Comment: тогда и ищите в `exs.index`

Comment: скиньте сюда файл csv

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if "China" in exs.index:
    print('Win')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы делал это так:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/geoMap.csv", skiprows=1)

print("Win" if df.loc[1:17, "Country"].str.contains("China").any() else "Fail")
```